# PhpMyAdmin: ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Помогите найти ошибку синтаксиса! Пытаюсь создать Базу данных. Но выдает ошибку #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

```
GREATE TABLE 'aliens_abduction' (
'first_name' VARHAR (30) ,
'last_name' VARHAR (30) ,
'when_it_happend' VARHAR (30) ,
'how_long' VARHAR (30) ,
'how_many' VARHAR (30) ,
'alien_description' VARHAR (100) ,
'what_they_did' VARHAR (100) ,
'fang_spotted' VARHAR (10) ,
'other' VARHAR (100) ,
'email' VARHAR (50)
```

);

Помогите понять!

Comment: Greate XD Creat Britain

Comment: CREATE, а не GREATE :)

Comment: А разве не VARCHAR пишется?

Comment: Он все равно пишет ошибку! #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''aliens_abduction' ( 'first_name' VARCHAR (30) , 'last_name' VARCHAR (30)

   CREATE TABLE 'aliens_abduction' (
   'first_name' VARCHAR (30) ,
   'last_name' VARCHAR (30) ,
   'when_it_happend' VARCHAR (30) ,
   'how_long' VARCHAR (30) ,
   'how_many' VARCHAR (30) ,
   'alien_description' VARCHAR (100) ,
   'what_they_did' VARCHAR (100) ,
   'fang_spotted' VARCHAR (10) ,
   'other' VARCHAR (100) ,
   'email' VARCHAR (50) 
   );

Comment: а зачем вы в кавычки все берете?

Comment: В учебной литературе прописано что все стандартные запросы, вводимые в MySQL должны заканчиваться точкой с запятой.

Comment: Имена таблиц и полей заключаются в такие кавычки `, а не в '

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE aliens_abduction ( 
first_name VARCHAR (30) , 
last_name VARCHAR (30) , 
when_it_happend VARCHAR (30) , 
how_long VARCHAR (30), 
how_many VARCHAR (30) , 
alien_description VARCHAR (100) , 
what_they_did VARCHAR (100) , 
fang_spotted VARCHAR (10) ,
other VARCHAR (100) , 
email VARCHAR (50) );
```

Comment: А разве кавычки не нужны?

Comment: @Arty21, обратные кавычки позволяют использовать спецсимволы (кроме обратных кавычек) в имени таблиц и столбцов.  
Они необязательные, если вы руководствуетесь здравым смыслом при именовании таблиц и столбцов.  
Еще они могут быть нужны для экранирования спецслов, которые вы (не дай бог!) захотите использовать в имени таблиц или столбцов.